# res, src and android Manifest

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am fairly new to android dev and I recently downloaded this bit of source code as an example. There is a folder called res, src and then an XML file.
I tried to use Android Studios to import the folder but it threw so many errors I don't know where to begin. Any help guys?

Do I need eclipse instead?

I've fixed some of them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Premature end of file" usually means that there's some syntax element missing.  If it's a Java source, it could mean something like a `{` without a matching `}`.  The compiler is expecting to see `}` or some other statement or something, and it hits the end of the file instead, so it complains.  The same could apply to XML files or any other language with syntaxes that have "beginning" and "ending" elements that must match.

Comment: @ajb the file in which the error message points to is empty. Completely blank.

Comment: Well, that's probably the problem, especially if it's supposed to be an XML file.  Why do you have a blank file in your folder?

Comment: @ajb it came with the example. So I make an empty files. With XML head and blank resources and that worked. Then I get this (See second log.)

Comment: Try searching StackOverflow for "no resource found that matches the give name".  You'll probably find some answers.  It's been a while since I've done any Android programming, so I won't be of much help.

Comment: If you could please share that project with us, on say [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/), this would be able to provide input in a better way.

Comment: @nIcEcOw https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzUtHtjvFjQCaVpDTGZPWnpIV0E/view?usp=sharing   THank you so much!!!!

Comment: @Rguarascia: To me, it appears as if the project is broken. It has many missing files for `dimen`. Seems like, there is somethingy wrong

Comment: @nIcEcOw I used SystemApp to apk then a apk Decompiler.

Comment: @Rguarascia: Ahha, might be this has caused the project to break with missing files.

Comment: @nIcEcOw so what should i do? It is for the AOSP keyboard. Android 5.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, ensure there is a new line at the end of the style.xml. Also ensure all your XML tags are well formed (opened and closed appropriately) and nested tags are fully enclosed within other tags. This error could also be returned if the XML used contains uppercase letters (even in the XML tags), or if you are passing spaces somewhere in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Did u copied all the other files like strings.XML ,yourActivity.java etc.. Or you just copied the activity.XML only. If yes then copy all other files too